# Question on $p-$group and group action.

Tags: group-theory

Let $P$ a finite non trivial $p-$group.

1) Show that if $P$ act on a finite set $X$, then $$|X|\equiv |X^P|\pmod p,$$
where $X^P=\{x\in X\mid \forall g\in P,\ g\cdot x=x\}$.

2) Show that $Z(P)\neq \{1\}$ where $$Z(P)=\{h\in P\mid \forall g\in P,gh=hg\}.$$

3) Show that $P$ is solvable.

**My answers**

1) I tried to use Burnside, but without of success. An other way I tried, is let $P$ of order $p^m$. If $x\in X^P$, then $g^kx\in X^P$ for all $k\leq m$ since $g(g^kx)=g^k(gx)=g^kx$. Then, $|X^p|\geq m$, but also not conclusif.

2) It's a consequence of the conjugacy class equation, so no problem.

3) I have no idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that $\;x\in X^p\iff \mathcal Orb(x)=\{x\}\;$ , so

$$|X|=\sum_{\text{over disjoint orbits}} |\mathcal Orb(x)|=|X^p|+\sum_{\text{over disjoint orbits},x\notin X^p} |\mathcal Orb(x)|$$

But it is always true that

$$|\mathcal Orb(x)|=[P\,:\,P_x]\;,\;\;P_x=\text{the isotropy group of}\;\;x$$

and this last index is *always* a **positive** power of $\;p\;$ for $\;x\notin X^p\;$ ( the power zero of $\;p\;$ are the ones in $\;X^p\;$), and then you finally get $\;|X|=|X^p|\pmod p\;$

For (3): prove, by induction on $\;n\;$ , with $\;|P|=p^n\;$ , that for *any* $\;0\le k\le n\;$ there always exists a **normal** subgroup $\;H\;$ of $\;P\;$ of order $\;p^k\;$ . Use point (2) to work with the quotient $\;P/\langle z\rangle\;,\;\;1\neq z\in Z(P)\;$